# How to create application registration from the command line and add and/or grant certain API permissions (ex. Microsoft Graph)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, az

From inside of an Azure DevOps release pipeline, I need to create an application registration and then set certain API permissions on that app registration.

Does anyone provide an example of how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is probably your best bet. We execute a PS script to create the AD App and assign specific roles to it.

I don't have access to our code at the minute, but it's very similar to this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/09/01/how-to-create-an-azure-ad-application-in-powershell/

Note: one thing we have struggled with that doesn't seem to be achievable via automation, is the "Grant Admin consent to this application" when assigning application permissions to the app.

Comment: I think that `az ad app permission grant admin-consent --id YOUR_ID_HERE` will handle your problem. That has to be done after the permissions have been added/created.